# MySQL Query and Pivot Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

My MySQL database has the following column headings:

```
month, typeOfWork, totalHours
```

I am interested in displaying the results according to typeOfWork and month. For example, all typeOfWork entries will be displayed in the first column on the left, and each field will total that particular typeOfWork in each column's specified month. As such, my SQL pivot table statement is currently:

```
SELECT
IFNULL(typeOfWork, 'Total') AS TypeOfWork,
SUM(IF(month='JAN',totalHours,NULL)) AS JAN,    
SUM(IF(month='FEB',totalHours,NULL)) AS FEB,    
SUM(IF(month='MAR',totalHours,NULL)) AS MAR,    
SUM(IF(month='APR',totalHours,NULL)) AS APR,    
SUM(IF(month='MAY',totalHours,NULL)) AS MAY,    
SUM(IF(month='JUN',totalHours,NULL)) AS JUN,    
SUM(IF(month='JUL',totalHours,NULL)) AS JUL,    
SUM(IF(month='AUG',totalHours,NULL)) AS AUG,
SUM(IF(month='SEP',totalHours,NULL)) AS SEP,    
SUM(IF(month='OCT',totalHours,NULL)) AS OCT,    
SUM(IF(month='NOV',totalHours,NULL)) AS NOV,    
SUM(IF(month='DEC',totalHours,NULL)) AS DEC

FROM $databasetable GROUP BY typeOfWork
WITH ROLLUP
```

I'm currently getting a syntax error specifying the last line (from 'DEC through to ROLLUP'). My confusion comes from the fact that I have simply adapted this table from another working pivot table in my script. I think the difference might be in my two requirements (sum totalHours where month equals column name AND typeOfWork equals typeOfWork in first column). I'm wondering if my IF statements require an AND clause?

Can anybody point me in the right direction with this pivot table? It would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query is correct.
Only one thing - DEC is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-6.html), this word cannot be used as object identifier directly; so, just quote it with backticks -

```
SELECT
IFNULL(typeOfWork, 'Total') AS TypeOfWork,
SUM(IF(month='JAN',totalHours,NULL)) AS JAN,    
...
SUM(IF(month='DEC',totalHours,NULL)) AS `DEC`

FROM $databasetable GROUP BY typeOfWork
```

Comment: You are my hero. This did the trick! I never would have guessed that, so thanks very much. :)