# In MySQL, How do you dynamically SELECT the values of one table, as columns in another?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, pivot-without-aggregate

*I'm no MySQL guru, but I get around the basic stuff pretty well. Thanks for your feedback.*

I have two tables `user` and `favorite`. Each user can have multiple unique favorites.

**table user u**

```
[ user_id + name  ]
  100     | Sally
```

**table favorite fav**

```
[ fav_id  + user_id +  fav_key  +  fav_val ]
  1       | 100     | icecream  |    mint
  2       | 100     | candybar  |  snickers
  3       | 100     | color     |    red
```

I want to create a `SELECT` statement that will turn the user's favorites into columns using the `fav_key` value as the column header. *The problem is I will never know what the `fav_val` value will be as these are user entered, so the column names have to be generated dynamically.

**SELECT ...**

```
[ user_id + name  + fav_icecream + fav_candybar + fav_color ]
  100     | Sally |    mint      |   snickers   |   red
```

With some distant thought of performance in mind -- one of the issues is that I don't want to run two `SELECT` statements to get the user data and the user favorites (plus I like the idea of having the columns dynamically named in this way).

**UPDATE**

So this is called, pivoting, excellent.

What if I don't ever know what the values are? I need to dynamically generate the columns from a query on favorites.

Comment: possible duplicate of [pivot in mysql queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133990/pivot-in-mysql-queries)

Comment: @Lukas_Eder I didn't know this was called pivoting. I guess if I knew what keyword to look up then that mightve been helpful. However I think this question is still useful to people not knowing what to search for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
Select fav.user_id, u.name 
       MAX(case WHEN fav.fav_key = 'icecream' then fav.fav_val end) as 'fav_icecream',
       MAX(case WHEN fav.fav_key = 'candybar'  then fav.fav_val end) as 'fav_candybar',
       MAX(case WHEN fav.fav_key = 'color'    then fav.fav_val end) as 'fav_color'
From favorite fav
     inner join users u on fav.user_id = u.user_id
group by fav.user_id
```

Working Example: [**DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61451)

**Note that:**  the demo is for MS SQL Server but it is working the same way for mysql, I just tried to give you a live demo.

Comment: the problem is I'm not going to know the full list of favorites, this only works if i know what the values are.

Comment: @MGQ nice demo! This is the first time I've gotten a code demo on my answer and I didnt even know you could do this +1 ... still need the dynamically generated columns though =]

Comment: @qodeninja, This is a popular problem that (in MS SQL Server) there is a workarounds, and for mysql there should be workarounds as well try searching for *Mysql PIVOT Table with dynamic columns* see this post for example in SO here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158230/mysql-pivot-table-with-dynamic-headers-based-on-single-column-data

Answer (score 3):

Essentially you want `PIVOT` functionality. Unfortunately, that's not natively supported by MySQL (unlike Oracle or SQL Server). There are many questions on StackOverflow showing how to work around that lacking functionality of MySQL:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+pivot+sql

Some examples:

- [pivot in mysql queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133990/pivot-in-mysql-queries)
- [MySQL Query and Pivot Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866105/mysql-query-and-pivot-tables)